# Redshift / Postgres SQL - Split Sequential Data Into Multiple Rows

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I'm creating a table from some data with the following query:

```
CREATE TABLE TableA AS
SELECT
    color,
    TRIM(Year) as year,
    ...
FROM
    TableB;
```

In most cases `year` will be a single year, but in certain cases we could have e.g. `2003-2006`

How can I create the table such that it turns

```
color | year
blue | 2003-2006
```

into

```
color | year
blue | 2003
blue | 2004
blue | 2005
blue | 2006
```

I tried fiddling with `generate_series` but it doesn't seem to work given our version:

```
dev=# CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE series_test AS SELECT generate_series(1,3); 
INFO:  Function "generate_series(integer,integer)" not supported.
ERROR:  Specified types or functions (one per INFO message) not supported on Redshift tables.
```

Comment: I would strongly advise you not to use CTAS, because you cannot control the columns encodings.  Redshift makes those choices and in my view makes extremely poor choices.

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate a tally table of some sort for this purpose.  Say 10 years is enough, you could do:

```
with n as (
      select row_number() over () as n
      from tableb
      limit 10
     )
select t.from_year + n.n - 1, t.color
from (select t.*,
             (case when year like '%-%' then split_part(year, '-', 1)::int
                   else year::int
              end) as from_year,
             (case when year like '%-%' then split_part(year, '-', 2)::int
                   else year::int
              end) as to_year
      from t
     ) t join
     n
     on t.from_year + n.n - 1 <= t.to_year;
```

This assumes that the table has enough rows to generate the numbers.  If your given table isn't big enough, then you can use a different table.

Comment: Hmmm I'm not able to get to this to work. I did the following:

`create temporary table test(color varchar(32), year varchar(32)); insert into years values ('red', '2013'); insert into years values ('blue', '2015-2018');`

And this code seemed to only produce years 2015 and 2016 for some reason

Comment: @ShaneOH .  . . This assumes that the table has at least 10 rows.

Comment: I see yup. Is Postgres too rigid such that it can't be further extensible/generalized? For example we could easily expect less than 10 rows total or more than 10 years in the range. Theoretically it could be anywhere from a single row of ("blue", 1950-2020) or 100K rows each with a single year

Comment: @ShaneOH . . . Postgres is just fine.  My understand is that you are using Redshift.

Comment: That's correct -- I just meant as Redshift uses Postgres under the hood -- but I guess Redshift may be more limited...

Comment: @ShaneOH . . . Redshift was based on an archaic version of Postgres and has significantly diverged from what is now Postgres.